# filter data in BigQuery based on importance of data points sql

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am merging two tables in BigQuery and filtering those on a couple of conditions. The code looks like this:

```
SELECT,
    d.id,
    d.duration,
    c.action,
    c.url
FROM
    (
        `table_action_url` c
        INNER JOIN `table_duration` d ON (d.id = c.id)
    )
WHERE c.url LIKE "https://www.mywebpage%" 
AND d.duration = '15000' 
AND c.action in ('First quartile', 'Midpoint', 'Third quartile', 'Complete')
```

The output is:

```
id      duration      action                    url 
1         15000        Midpoint           https://www.mywebpage_fashion
1         15000        Complete           https://www.mywebpage_fashion
2         15000        First quartile     https://www.mywebpage_home
2         15000        Midpoint           https://www.mywebpage_home
```

I need to add a logic that would grab only one value from action. And the priorities are `Complete`, `Third quartile` etc. So the code needs to compare `ids` and `urls` and if the max values are `Complete` (for the same ids & urls), then grab that.
Desired output is:

```
id      duration      action                    url 
1         15000        Complete           https://www.mywebpage_fashion
2         15000        Midpoint           https://www.mywebpage_home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and generic way I see here is just to wrap up your existing query with below code

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE 
  ARRAY_AGG(current_query_result 
    ORDER BY CASE action
      WHEN 'Complete' THEN 1
      WHEN 'Third quartile' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Midpoint' THEN 3
      WHEN 'First quartile' THEN 4
    END
    LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM (
  SELECT,
    d.id,
    d.duration,
    c.action,
    c.url
  FROM `table_action_url` c
  INNER JOIN `table_duration` d USING(id)
  WHERE c.url LIKE "https://www.mywebpage%" 
  AND d.duration = '15000' 
  AND c.action in ('First quartile', 'Midpoint', 'Third quartile', 'Complete')
) current_query_result
GROUP BY id, url
```

with output

```
Row id  duration    action      url  
1   1   15000       Complete    https://www.mywebpage_fashion    
2   2   15000       Midpoint    https://www.mywebpage_home
```

As you can see the way to order candidates and pick one is implemented via below fragment

```
ORDER BY CASE action
  WHEN 'Complete' THEN 1
  WHEN 'Third quartile' THEN 2
  WHEN 'Midpoint' THEN 3
  WHEN 'First quartile' THEN 4
END
LIMIT 1
```

There is another option to achieve the same with less verbose, easier to manage and probably more efficient (this is not proven - just my feeling) code

```
ORDER BY STRPOS('Complete, Third quartile, Midpoint, First quartile', action)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions and a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn)
FROM (
    SELECT,
        d.id,
        d.duration,
        c.action,
        c.url,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY CASE c.action
            WHEN 'Complete' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Third quartile' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Midpoint' THEN 3
            WHEN 'First quartile' THEN 4
        END) rn
    FROM `table_action_url` c
    INNER JOIN `table_duration` d ON d.id = c.id
    WHERE 
        c.url LIKE "https://www.mywebpage%" 
        AND d.duration = '15000' 
        AND c.action in ('First quartile', 'Midpoint', 'Third quartile', 'Complete')
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this query only returns "Complete" results...

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, you can do this using aggregation:

```
SELECT d.id, d.duration,
       ( ARRAY_AGG(c.action ORDER BY ao.ord DESC LIMIT 1) )[ORDINAL(1)] as action,
       ( ARRAY_AGG(c.url ORDER BY ao.ord DESC LIMIT 1) )[ORDINAL(1)] as url
FROM `table_action_url` c JOIN
     `table_duration` d
     ON d.id = c.id JOIN
     (SELECT 'Complete' as action, 1 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Third quartile' as action, 2 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Midpoint' as action, 3 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 'First quartile' as action, 4 as ord
     ) ao
     ON c.action = ao.action      
WHERE c.url LIKE 'https://www.mywebpage%' AND
      d.duration = '15000' 
GROUP BY d.id, d.duration;
```